# Identifying incorrectly sampled recordings and finding their actual sampling rate

Tags: frequency, audio-processing, resampling, speech

I have a dataset that contains a lot of recordings sampled incorrectly. This incorrect resampling could be explained in two ways:

1. A recording **S**, which was recorded with a sampling rate of 16kHz, was upsampled to a sampling rate of 48kHz. This upsampled recording **S** was mixed with other recordings in a dataset containing recordings originally sampled at 48kHz.
2. A recording **L** was recorded with a sampling rate of 16kHz, processed and saved with a sampling rate of 48kHz without resampling. This recording **L** was mixed with other recordings of the dataset originally sampled at 48kHz.

Given a dataset containing such incorrectly sampled files, is there an existing automated way to identify files **S** and **L** from the dataset containing millions of recordings, all originally sampled at 48kHz?

It would also be interesting to know if there is a way to identify the correct sampling rate of the file **L** without having any prior meta-information about it.

Answer (score 4):

You could start by applying a k-means or PCA on the spectrum of the audio files.

For the high frequencies, what I would expect from your description.

- The **S** recordings should have a sharp cutoff at ~8kHz.
- The **L** recordings should have a sharp cutoff at ~24kHz.
- Supposing the 48kHz contains mostly speech those should have a gradual reduction of the spectral energy after 8kHz.

If that doesn't work you could label some files manually and apply a Gaussian Mixtrure Model.

In the low frequencies (only help to distinguish between **L** and **S** not the 48kHz recordings), you could look for 50Hz/60Hz hum, or hum filter (a notch in that frequency). Some recorders will have a high pass filter but I don't that could be any frequency, so it doesn't help.

If you want to put still more energy you could have a look on [vocal tract length features](https://www.spraak.org/documentation/spr_tut_vtln.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Bob, I agree to what you've mentioned. So in my case, I have created a small CNN based classifier that detects this sharp cut-off and returns the approximate sampling rate. But, I was thinking if there's an existing mathematical way or algorithm to this, that would have been really helpful.
I am still not sure about your second point, how you are detecting L as all the files are sampled at 48kHz and will be having sharp cutoff at 24kHz freq.

Comment: They will be different, because the *L* set will have the spectrum stretched. A natural speech recording would have little energy above say 10kHz, but the stretched spectrum will have a significant portion of the energy above 10kHz.

Comment: Very reasonable. I totally get it now. Thanks for the response again.